# Use an int when accessing a name in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, var

I'm currently build a windows phone 8 application using c# and I'm wondering how I can achieve this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 18; i++)
{
    _(i)Score.Text = "whatever here";
}
```

which when run should be something like:

```
_1Score.Text = "whatever here";
_2Score.Text = "whatever here";
_3Score.Text = "whatever here";
etc.
```

How am I able to achieve this as just putting `_(i)Score` doesn't work.

EDIT: What im doing is making a scorecard app which has a table overview. I've named each one as 1Socre, 2Score, 3Score etc. and I just want to update what they say. They are all textboxes and I'm just replacing the text inside.

Please Help.
Thanks

Comment: Are all these Elements in a StackPanel, Grid, Canvas or somthing else? or are they in a list?

Comment: Even though I already answered, it may be beneficial to explain what you're actually trying to do because this seems like an [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341).  Doing so may yield better code.

Comment: is the `UIElement` named "_1Score" or is that just the variable name?

Comment: the UIElement is name _1Score eg. `x:name="_1Score"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This most direct way to implement what you're doing:

```
var name = string.Format("_{0}Score", i);
this.Controls[name].Text = "...";
```

Knowing the types (based on @sa_ddam213's comment):

```
foreach(var textBox in Children.OfType<TextBox>().Where(txt => txt.Name.EndsWith("Score")))
{
    textBox.Text = "...";
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more as it has an error over the 'Controls' part saying '... does not contain a definition for Controls' Thanks

Comment: @swenflea:  I cannot without knowing the parent type of `_1Score` (and others...).

Comment: It's all textboxes inside a grid

Comment: Then change `Controls` to `Children.OfType<TextBox>()`